# Need help in understanding terminology (display server)

Tags: linux, graphics, terminology, display-server

What is expected from the program to be called a display server? In other words what, for example, X11 and Wayland have in common?

Is display server has the same meaning as windowing system? Atleast on wikipedia both X11 and Wayland are listed in both article.

These articles on wikipedia are unclear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a display server is more or less a windowing system. But unlike most windowing systems it can be used by remote applications (that are considered "clients"):

- This is why you have a `DISPLAY=:0` variable in your Linux environment, that variable can contain the address of the host that acts as the display server (`DISPLAY=192.168.67.212:0`).
- Back in the 80-90's, when people were doing time-sharing on Unix machines, GUI users used "X Terminals" that were remotely connected (serial or LAN). These would handle user display and user input (keyboard and mouse), and acted as "display servers" for the "client" applications (that technically could run on several different Unix machines)(*). The next generation (late 90s) was just running the "XWindows86" (or was it XFree86) server (an implementation of the X server) on a PC running Windows (or OS/2).
- When you connect by SSH to a system that has graphical support, you can use your local system as a display server for GUI applications that run on the remote.

(*) Security was low, a common prank was to start some semi-NSFW application on a colleague's X terminal, you only needed to know its IP address for this.